# Dart: Map.update error "Uncaught Error: TypeError: type '(dynamic) => num' is not a subtype of type '(String) => String'"

Tags: dart

I have a Map of List of Maps as a set of data (`dataMap`) and want to transform like below with using `Map.update` method. This caught an error: `Uncaught Error: TypeError: Closure 'main__convertIdFromStringToDocRef_closure': type '(dynamic) => num' is not a subtype of type '(String) => String'`. I should misunderstand something about `Map.update`, but am not sure what it is... Can you please teach me?

```
void main() {
  num _convertStringToNum(dynamic str, String collection) {
    if (str is String) { return num.tryParse(str); }
    if (str is num) { return str; }
    return null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _convertIdFromStringToNum(Map<String, dynamic> map, String collection) {
    map.update('id', (mapId) => _convertStringToNum(mapId, collection));
    return map;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {
    'types': [
      {
        'id': '123',
        'name': 'foo',
      },
      {
        'id': '234',
        'name': 'bar',
      }
    ],
  };

  dataMap.update('types', (types) {
    if (!(types is List<Map<String, dynamic>>)) { return null; }
    types.map((Map<String, dynamic> type) => _convertIdFromStringToNum(type, 'types')).toList();
    return types;
  });
}
```

This code can run on DartPad.

Comment: please provide: `_convertIdFromStringToDocRef` or try this: `_convertIdFromStringToDocRef(type['id'], 'types')` since it expects `id` as `string` (see error message)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the `_convertIdFromStringToDocRef ` should be `_convertIdFromStringToNum`. I modfied the question.

Comment: try solution: `_convertIdFromStringToDocRef(type['id'], 'types')`

Comment: Thank you, but it failed with an error `Uncaught Error: TypeError: "123": type 'JSString' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`. I have 2 functions and it is the second one with arguments `(Map<String>, String)`.

Comment: Can You explain in Your question what You want to achieve? You want to convert `id` values that is numbers to be `number` ?

Comment: Basically yes. To simplify the problem I picked up some fields on `dataMap` and change data types on it. I actually have more fields on it and use these methods several times, and also the real transformation I want to do is to convert `id` values to Firestore's `DocumentReference`. But the error message is same (mostly similar) with what I described.

Comment: it should be done a bit differently, so I’ll respond in 1-2 (busy now) or try to rewrite it Yourself. so up to You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. (But still have an unclear points on the real cause...)

The problem is with `.map(MapEntry<K2, V2> f(K key, V value))` method. The argument of the method is a function `MapEntry<K2, V2> f(K key, V value)`, and as described in the code I expect `Map<String, dynamic>` on its `key`, but actually it is `JsLinkedHashMap<String, String>` (the value is `String`). As I tried assigning non-String value through `map.update('id', (mapId) => _convertStringToNum(mapId, collection));` in the function `_convertIdFromStringToNum`, it throw the exception.

So I changed the code as below. I create a new `Map<String, dynamic>` (`newMap`) and then do `.update()` on it.

```
void main() {
  num _convertStringToNum(dynamic str, String collection) {
    if (str is String) { return num.tryParse(str); }
    if (str is num) { return str; }
    return null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _convertIdFromStringToNum(Map<String, dynamic> map, String collection) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> newMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);
    newMap.update('id', (mapId) => _convertStringToNum(mapId, collection));
    return newMap;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {
    'types': [
      {
        'id': '123',
        'name': 'foo',
      },
      {
        'id': '234',
        'name': 'bar',
      }
    ],
  };

  dataMap.update('types', (types) {
    if (!(types is List<Map<String, dynamic>>)) { return null; }
    return types.map((Map<String, dynamic> type) => _convertIdFromStringToNum(type, 'types')).toList();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had strange issue as in Yours too.

Seems like if map entry is initialised with `String` it cannot be modified to `num`:

```
Map<String, dynamic> item = {
 "id": "123",
 "name": "TEST"
};

// this throws exception that `item['id']` has `String` value and we are trying to replace it with `num`
item['id'] = num.tryParse(item['id']);
```

I found workaround by creating custom class with constructor which converts input to necessary type of field:

```
class Type {
  num id;
  String name;

  num convertToNum(dynamic input) {
    switch (input.runtimeType) {
      case int: break;
      case num: break;
      case String: return num.tryParse(input); break;
      default: return null;
    }
    return input;
  }

  Type(id, name) {
    this.id = convertToNum(id);
    this.name = name;
  }

  static fromMap(Map map) {
    return Type(map['id'], map['name']); 
  }

  Map toMap() {
    return {
      "id": this.id,
      "name": this.name
    };
  }
}
```

and while iterating list using `.map` I'm creating instance of `Type` and calling `toMap` method which returns unique object.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {
    'types': [
      {
        'id': 111,
        'name': 'foo',
      },
      {
        'id': '123',
        'name': 'foo',
      },
      {
        'id': '234',
        'name': 'bar',
      }
    ],
  };

  dataMap['types'] = (dataMap['types'] is List<Map>)
      ? dataMap['types'].map((type) => Type.fromMap(type).toMap())
      : null;

  print(dataMap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't get an exception with the first snippet of yours and `tryParce()` is successfully modified String to num on DartPad... But your solution works well too. I'm still want to know the reason why my code doesn't work, but this can be the solution.